# how to make the notification appear on the locked screen of iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am having application in which i am showing notifications .The notifications are displayed properly when my app is in background but the problem is notification does not appear when the iphone screen is locked.Please help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a user preference that can be activated in the Notifications section of the Settings app. There is no way to control this from within your app.

Comment: how to activate this user preference in Notifications section of Settingd app.